# How to unit test Next.js dynamic components?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, jestjs, next.js

The Next.js `dynamic()` HOC components aren't really straightforward to tests. I have 2 issues right now;

- First jest is failing to compile dynamic imports properly (`require.resolveWeak is not a function` - seems to be added by next babel plugin)
- Second I can't get good coverage of the `modules` logic; looks like it's simply not run when trying to render a dynamic component.

Comment: any luck? @Simon Boudrias

Comment: I'm also interested in this. Seems like the only way to do it is to either expose a mocked require.resolveWeak from jest, or to have a custom babel plugin which will not use the handler-imports plugin logic that next js uses. See https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/2d8c19a450b21df4e9f6ab8fe61c2272a0b9ac9f/server/build/babel/plugins/handle-import.js for the plugin that changes the imports into requrie.resolveWeak

Comment: Went with mocking next/dynamic... ```jest.mock('next/dynamic', () => () => 'Dynamic')```

Comment: can you add an example for mocking the dynamic import? I have to test this:

const DynamicDrawer = dynamic({
  loader: () => import('./SimpleDrawer/index'),
  loading: () => null,
});


but I'm getting this error:  Warning: <%s /> is using incorrect casing. Use PascalCase for React components, or lowercase for HTML elements.%s

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's assume we have a component like this (using a dynamic import):

```js
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const ReactSelectNoSSR = dynamic(() => import('../components/select'), {
    loading: () => <Input />,
    ssr: false
});

export default () => (
    <>
        <Header />
        <ReactSelectNoSSR />
        <Footer />
    </>
);
```

The dynamic import support offered by Next.js **does not** expose a way to preload the dynamically imported components in Jest’s environment.
However, thanks to [jest-next-dynamic](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/jest-next-dynamic), we can render the full component tree instead of the loading placeholder.

You'll need to add [babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node) to your `.babelrc` like so.

```js
{
  "plugins": ["babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node"]
}
```

Then, you can use `preloadAll()` to render the component instead of the loading placeholder.

```js
import preloadAll from 'jest-next-dynamic';
import ReactSelect from './select';

beforeAll(async () => {
    await preloadAll();
});
```

---

[Source](https://leerob.io/blog/things-ive-learned-building-nextjs-apps/)

Answer (score 10):

The following will load the required component.
You can also use similar approach to load all components before hand.

```
jest.mock('next/dynamic', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: (...props) => {
    const dynamicModule = jest.requireActual('next/dynamic');
    const dynamicActualComp = dynamicModule.default;
    const RequiredComponent = dynamicActualComp(props[0]);
    RequiredComponent.preload
      ? RequiredComponent.preload()
      : RequiredComponent.render.preload();
    return RequiredComponent;
  },
}));
```

Answer (score 8):

You can add the following to your Jest setup ex: `setupTests.ts`

```
jest.mock('next/dynamic', () => () => {
    const DynamicComponent = () => null;
    DynamicComponent.displayName = 'LoadableComponent';
    DynamicComponent.preload = jest.fn();
    return DynamicComponent;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Although a hacky solution, what I did was to simply mock `next/dynamic` by extracting the import path and returning that import:

```
jest.mock('next/dynamic', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: (...props) => {
    const matchedPath = /(.)*(\'(.*)\')(.)*/.exec(props[0].toString());
    if (matchedPath) return require(matchedPath[3]);
    else return () => <></>;
  },
}));
```

Comment: How would that work? You are passing an anonymous function to next/dynamic so you can't extract the path from it

Answer (score 3):

Here is an easy fix, which:

- Doesn't require any 3rd party libraries
- Still renders the dynamic component (e.g. snapshots will work)

**SOLUTION:**

1. Mock the `next/dynamic` module, by creating a mock file in `__mocks__/next/dynamic.js` [Jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks#mocking-node-modules)
2. Copy and paste the following code:

```
const dynamic = (func) => {
    const functionString = func.toString()
    const modulePath = functionString.match(/"(.*?)"/)[1]

    const namedExport = functionString.match(/mod\.(.+?(?=\)))/)
    const componentName = namedExport ? namedExport[1] : 'default'

    return require(modulePath)[componentName]
}

export default dynamic
```

3. The above code assumes that you are using the `dynamic()` function for `default` and `named exports` as documented in the [Next.js docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import). I.e.:

```
// default
const DynamicHeader = dynamic(() =>
  import('../components/header')
)

// named export
const DynamicComponent = dynamic(() =>
  import('../components/hello').then((mod) => mod.Hello)
)
```

That's it! Now dynamic imports should work in all your test suites :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're having the first issue with Next8, you can mock the dynamic import with this:

```
jest.mock('next-server/dynamic', () => () => 'Dynamic');
```

For reference, see:

https://spectrum.chat/next-js/general/with-jest-and-dynamic-imports-broken~25905aad-901e-41d8-ab3e-9f97eeb51610?m=MTU1MzA5MTU2NjI0Nw==

https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/6187#issuecomment-467134205