# Dynamic import failed with JEST and React testing library in nextjs 12 use SWC (not use babel)

Tags: next.js, jestjs, swc

I have problems about testing component that it's used dynamic import in nextjs 12.
I show up some info about technical:

- NextJS 12 use SWC (not use babel)
- React 18
- Jest + React testing library

Here example:
Component:

```
import styles from '@/pages/index.module.css';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
const Hello = dynamic(() => import('../components/Hello'));

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
....
```

File test:

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import Home from '@/pages/index';

describe('Home', () => {
  it('renders a heading', () => {
    render(<Home />);

    const heading = screen.getByRole('heading', {
      name: /welcome to next\.js!/i,
    });

    expect(heading).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByText('Hello')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

And I get error:

```
 <DsPropertyContent/> test › normal work correctly

    Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

I tried with solution ([How to unit test Next.js dynamic components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46906948/how-to-unit-test-next-js-dynamic-components)) but i don't want to use babel because app would be run failed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are rendering `<Hello />` within your `Home` component, try updating your test to use `async/await`, and use `findByText` instead of `getByText`.

```
describe('Home', () => {
  it('renders a heading', async () => {
    render(<Home />);

    const heading = screen.getByRole('heading', {
      name: /welcome to next\.js!/i,
    });

    expect(heading).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(await screen.findByText('Hello')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

React Testing Library docs about async/await:

https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/